# USB Like Boot Drive On Second Parition

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, partitioning, ssd

I am trying to make my second partition on my SSD, D:\ to act as if it was a USB Drive plugged in. I have tried:

- unetbootin, with the override flag parameter of "installtype=USB targetdrive=F:\"
- LiLi, aka LinuxLive USB Creator
- Manually dragging over the files from the usb drive to the second partition on the SSD and formatting the SSD as FAT32
- rufus wont detect my second parition, EVEN if i turn on the secret experimental option of Ctrl+Alt+F to show internal drives

I have spent the past 6 hours sifting through forums and stackexchange posts haha, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSD (rightly) has firmware installed to identify it as an internal disk, and not as a user-removeable one (one that a USB firmware would be configured to). You don't want to mess with the firmware that the SSD has to make it look removable, because it seems from your question you dont have experience modifying it and you are likely to lose all data (Its much harder to recover from an SSD compared to a mechanical hard drive as well). This firmware is the reason why, when you plug in an external hard drive to your computer, it sometimes shows up as an internal disk and not within your removeable drives (within Windows File Explorer for example).

You can still install boot files to the second partition and register it with your bootloader, for example, using EasyBCD to choose to boot from it. You might also be able to register it in your EFI bootloader so that you can see it from BIOS and directly boot into that partition. Whatever you are hoping to achieve by booting from a USB device, you can still do without it seeing the partition as a removable drive. If you are on BIOS/MBR then I strongly recommend EasyBCD to add it to your Windows boot menu.

Comment: Can you elaborate on using EasyBCD to do this?

Comment: Last time I tried to use the tool it gave me a message about alot of its features being disabled due. Even when booting windows with legacy csm and secureboot off.

Comment: You have to go on EasyBCD and add the second partition, selecting what type it is (ie WIndows, Linux, Iso, etc) and then choose the partition. Then, make sure you install the bootlaoder to MBR (EasyBCD's one), so that on startup it asks you where to boot from. I haven't used the program in a few years but I know it works as I used it many times in the past. Here is an image of what I mean: https://mk0intowindows84fvao.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/EasyBCD-for-Windows-8.jpg. AFAIK it doesnt work easily with UEFI machines, so you may want to install Grub and use that instead of BCD